# How to restrict ManyToManyField in ModelViewSet for no super users?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models linked by a ManyToManyField relationship.

```py
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Device(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='devices', blank=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='devices')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Device"
        verbose_name_plural = "Devices"
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My Viewset:

```py
class SiteViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return Site.objects.all().prefetch_related("devices")
        else:
            return Site.objects.filter(
                devices__users=self.request.user
            ).prefetch_related("devices").distinct()
```

My Serializers:

```py
class SiteDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id', 'name', )


class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    devices = SiteDeviceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = "__all__"
```

If I access my view with a superuser, it works well I have all the results.
Example:

```json
 "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "devices": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "test 2"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Site test 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "devices": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Test 3"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Site test 2"
        }
    ]
```

I have created another user `user1` who is **not** a super user.
I also added this user in the `users` of the device `test 1`.
When I access the view with this user I get:

```json
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "devices": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "test 2"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Site test 1"
        }
    ]
```

We can see that the `Site test 2`  does not appear, which is perfect.
But I see the device `test 2` and I shouldn't see it, I added the user `user1` only to the device `test 1`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the `devices` as well with a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class SiteViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return Site.objects.all().prefetch_related('devices')
        else:
            return Site.objects.filter(
                devices__users=self.request.user
            ).prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('devices', Device.objects.filter(users=self.request.user))
            ).distinct()
```